# Why doesn't this CSS :not() declaration filter down?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class, negation

I want to select spans that are not the descendants of a specific class, let's call it "no". Here's my CSS:

```css
div:not(.no) span{background-color:#00f;}
```

Here's the HTML

```html
<div>
    <span>yes 1</span>
</div>
<div class="no">
        <span>no 1</span>
</div>
<div class="no">
    <div>
           <span>no 2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Two questions:

1. Why does my CSS apply to both yes 1 and no 2?
2. Why does the whole thing break if I switch to a universal selector?

   ```css
   *:not(.no) span{background-color:#00f;}
   ```

Here's the code in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stephaniehobson/JtNZm/

Comment: Related: [CSS negation pseudo-class :not() for parent/ancestor elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084112/css-negation-pseudo-class-not-for-parent-ancestor-elements)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Both of the `span` elements' parent `div` elements don't have the class `no`, regardless of whether any other ancestors do have it or not:

   ```html
   <div> <!-- This is div:not(.no), pretty much a given -->
       <span>yes 1</span>
   </div>
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="no"> <!-- In this case, although this is div.no... -->
       <div>        <!-- ... this is div:not(.no)! -->
              <span>no 2</span>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. Both `html` and `body`, which are ancestors of your `div` and `span` elements, satisfy `*:not(.no)` when using a universal selector (or rather, when omitting a type selector). This causes *all* of your `span` elements to have the background color.

One solution to this is to anchor your negation filter to the `body` element using the child combinator, if your top-level `div` elements will always be children of `body`:

```css
body > div:not(.no) span { background-color: #00f; }
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/JtNZm/1)

Another solution is to simply use override styles.

Comment: It's a small part of a much larger jQuery optimization problem and I can't be certain of the relation of any of the elements to each other in the DOM.

This was kind of a tangent that was bothering me, but it's not any more :)

Comment: +1. Thanks. I finally understand what my problem was, that prompted me to ask the related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869061/is-the-css-not-selector-supposed-to-work-with-distant-descendants .

Answer (score 4):

BoltClock is correct.  It might make more sense if you phrase the selector like this:

> Select any `span` element
>   that is descended from a `div` element
>   whose `class` value does not contain the word `no`.

Each of the selected `span`s in your example is in fact descended from a `div` whose `class` value does not contain the word `no`—the fact that the second of them is also descended from a `div` whose `class` value *does* contain the word `no` doesn’t negate (ha!) the previous statement.

What’s interesting is I would wager that if you moved the second `no` down a level, the second `span` would still be matched.  CSS doesn’t have a notion of element proximity, so any ancestor `div` should suffice to match the selector, regardless of whether it’s “closer” to the `span` or not.

Comment: I tried it an you're right, if I move the second no down a level the second span is still matched.

More frustrating than interesting :P

Comment: Holy crap, it's Eric Meyer! :D

Answer (score 0):

I think the best choice is to split your statement into 2:

```
div span { background-color:#00f; }
.no span { background-color:#fff; }
```

You can see the effect here: http://jsfiddle.net/JHTqp/

Comment: Unfortunately it's a small part of a much larger jQuery optimization problem, this was just my test case.