# CSS for a div and its children excluding one particular child and that child's children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have nested blocks like this, I don't know how many nested block there :

```
<div class="my-class">
   ...
   <div class="exclude-my-class">
      <div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <div>
      </div>
   </div>
   ...
</div>
```

I want to write styles for "my-class" and its children but exclude "exclude-my-class" and its children **using css**. I don't know in which level can be "exclude-my-class" classes

Something like

```
.my-class:not(.exclude-my-class), 
.my-class *:not(.exclude-my-class, .exclude-my-class *){
    //styles
}
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: `.my-class > div:not(.exclude-my-class)`

Comment: I don't know how many nested blocks there, so > cant work , it for only first level childs

Comment: Your children of my class has a class 2 (which isn't a good name but what ever i guess it's an example). So you would just have to do .2:not(.exclude-my-class) 3. 3 is supposed to be the children right?

Comment: That numbers are just for displaying nested blocks, I dont know about that classes, Try to understand problem and suggest any solution if you can, not just type something.

Comment: Chill. You wrote something incorrect in your question and you want someone to randomly understand your thoughts. If you can't explain correctly what's your problem and expect someone to understand that wht you wrote doesn't exist in your real code then you have some issues understanding human intercations.

Comment: Why are you downwote me, because of in my code class names 1, 2, 3 ?

Comment: @TigranBabajanyan Will the div being skipped always at the first position?

Comment: no, there can be many nested blocks

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: @TigranBabajanyan multiple nested blocks is not a concern, take a look at my answer and you'll understand what I'm asking.

Comment: @ser00ne in this case your solution not working https://jsfiddle.net/n0jpkxzL/7/

Comment: @TigranBabajanyan Ah, I see.  You should edit your question to include these particulars otherwise you will have to explain each of these aspects to each person foolish enough to help you. Good luck, sir.

Answer (score 1):

The question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870564/how-to-exclude-a-class-with-all-children-in-style-definition).

Borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/why-is-my-jquery-not-selector-not-working-in-css/10711731#10711731), you can’t. The [`:not()` pseudo-class in Selectors level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) is very limited by itself. You can only pass a single simple selector as an argument to `:not()`. This means you can pass only any one of these at a time:

- Universal selector (`*`), optionally with a [namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#univnmsp)
- Type selector (`a`, `div`, `span`, `ul`, `li`, etc), optionally with a [namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#univnmsp)
- Attribute selector (`[att]`, `[att=val]`, etc), optionally with a [namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#univnmsp)
- Class selector (`.class`)
- ID selector (`#id`)
- Pseudo-class (`:pseudo-class`)

Answer (score 0):

HTMl:

```
<div class="my-class">
   <div class="exclude-my-class">
      <div >
        Skipped
      </div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <div>
      not skipped
      </div>
   </div>   

   <div class="exclude-my-class">
      <div >
      skipped
      </div>
      <div >
      skipped
      </div>
   </div>
    <div>
      <div>
      not skipped
      </div>
      <div>
      not skipped
      </div>
   </div>   
    <div>
      <div>
      not skipped
      </div>
   </div>   
    <div>
      <div>
      not skipped
      </div>
   </div>   
</div>
```

CSS: Select all the children of the children of my-class but not children if the direct child of my-class is exclude my class.

```
.my-class div:not(.exclude-my-class) div{
    background-color: red;
}
```

CSS: Select all the children of my class but not children with exclude-my-class.

```
.my-class > div:not(.exclude-my-class){
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Its not solution for me, beacause of there can be many nested blocks

Comment: Many nested blocks where? In this solution every block is taken in to account. You can have a lot of exclude my class. @TigranBabajanyan

Comment: this is your code result https://jsfiddle.net/n0jpkxzL/1/    or https://jsfiddle.net/n0jpkxzL/2/

Comment: You are  a generous, but as I said there can be many nested blocks like this  https://jsfiddle.net/n0jpkxzL/4/

Comment: In the first selector you can replace to `.my-class div:not(.exclude-my-class) ****` it will work in your last example. @TigranBabajanyan

Comment: As i said skipped div not always at the first position https://jsfiddle.net/n0jpkxzL/6/

Comment: @TigranBabajanyan Add to your main question all the relevant info. You keep adding new stuff every time. Edit your question and add every possible case you have.

Answer (score -1):

Use below code

```
.my-class : not(.exclude-my-class)
```

Comment: Its absolutely not solution, it will exlude only childs which have class "exclude-my-class", not its childs