# CSS selectors that is not applied if hierarchy contains an element?

Tags: css, css-selectors

There are tens of CSS rules I would like to be applied on a section of a page - this part is easy:

```
.generalStyles a,p,button,div.foo {
  /* many styling rules here*/
}
```

However, when I mark a section of a page with `class="generalStyles"`, I would like certain subsections not to inherit those styles, such as descendants of `class="noGeneralStyles"` (1). This should work with arbitrary nesting.

What I am looking for is a selector that could be translated into:

> Inherit CSS rules if you are a descendant of .generalStyles, but not
>   when .noGeneralStyles is a closer parent

An interactive jsFiddle example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/maros_urbanec/sJP8q/2/)

**EDIT:** The solution (if there is any) should not make any assumptions of inner HTML

---

(1) - the reason is there are way too many CSS rules to reset

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to limit or otherwise control inheritance chains using selectors alone, not even through combining `:not()` and descendant selectors for the reasons given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084112/css-negation-pseudo-class-not-for-parent-ancestor-elements/7084147#7084147) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540708/why-doesnt-this-css-not-declaration-filter-down/8540726#8540726). You will have to provide an overriding rule for elements within `.generalStyles .noGeneralStyles`.

Comment: This is prone to "infinite loops" - is another set of rules needed for `.generalStyles .noGeneralStyles .generalStyles`? I fear that your answer might be correct, though, and CSS is not yet ready for "widget" type development

Comment: @user2394179: Yes, unfortunately. There's no way of specifying the closer of two ancestors to a particular descendant - that's just not how selectors work. A future spec will allow you to block inheritance for specific or (almost) all properties using property syntax - see [here](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-cascade/#defaulting) - but it'll be a long time before implementations arrive.

Comment: Just curious, how he nested the styles in his fiddle? Edit: I see now, SCSS hehe, I was expecting that in External Resources

Answer (score 2):

How about using direct descendant selectors? `>` means it will select `button` tag, which is `direct` child to an element having class `noGeneralStyles` or `generalStyles`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sJP8q/1/)

```
.noGeneralStyles > button {
    color: black;
}
.generalStyles > button {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately - no. Firstly, they can be arbitrarily nested and secondly, such approach is in fact a CSS reset - which I would like to avoid (too many rules to be reset).

Comment: @user2394179 I didn't got what you are trying to achieve here, I went according to the text written in your buttons

Comment: This answer would be my guess too. @user2394179, maybe you could add a code to your startpost which clarifies which elements you DO and DO NOT want to style.

Comment: @user2394179 as Bolt already explained you, you cannot simply reset the style using ANY selector whatsoever, you need to override them.