# CSS using not in get all with pattern

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

i have this style in my index.css :

```
.sidebar-5 {
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    float: right;
    height: 214px;
    width: 498px;
    border-radius:none !important;
}
```

and i can use this style to set all class for `sidebar` and `box-sml`

```
[class^="sidebar"] , [class^="box-sml"]  :not(#sidebar-5) {
   border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px; 
}
```

or

```
[class^="sidebar"] :not(#sidebar-5), [class^="box-sml"] {
   border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px; 
}
```

i want to use `not()` for skip `#sidebar-5` element and i can not do it. how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Using `:not()` with descendant selectors is often problematic. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869061/is-the-css-not-selector-supposed-to-work-with-distant-descendants/20869102#20869102) and the ones linked to from there for some explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
#sidebar-5{
      border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
    }
```

Or if its a class:

```
   .sidebar-5{
      border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
    }
```

Comment: The `!important` is not necessary.