# Selecting all <p> in .class except for those in <footer>

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to select all p's in the `.content-area` except for the p's under `<footer>`. How do I do this in CSS? By the way, `<footer>` is inside `.content-area`

In any case, this is the CSS rule I want to put on all p's under `.content-area`

```
.class p {padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;}
```

EDIT: As per the comment below, the source code looks something like this.

```
<div class="content-area">
    <img />
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <footer> 
        <p></p>
        <ul></ul>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4):

You If the paragraphs are directly within the `.class` element, you should use [children selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) as `.class > p` to select the `p` elements.

```css
.class > p  {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/huhawabi/1/edit)**.

In order to select the nested `<p>` elements excluding those are nested within `footer`, you can use [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot) pseudo-class as follows:

```css
.class > p,
.class :not(footer) p {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

**[Updated Demo](http://jsbin.com/huhawabi/2/edit)**.

However, you can also override the applied style to the paragraphs inside the footer.

Comment: Be careful when using `:not()` with descendant selectors - in particular if you have more than two levels of nesting, it may match the wrong elements. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869061/is-the-css-not-selector-supposed-to-work-with-distant-descendants)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to reset the styles of your paragraphs inside the `<footer>`:

```
.class p {padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;}

.class footer p {padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0;}
```

---

Based on your edit, you can use direct child `>` selector:

```
.content-area > p {
   padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the immediate children selector

```
.content-area > p {
   padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

this will apply the style only to the direct children of `.content-area`