# How can I style <code> only if its parent is not <pre>?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm integrating wmd-editor like the one used here.

For inline code blocks like `this one`, the html generated is:

```
<code>this one</code>
```

For multiline code like:

```
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
```

The html generated is:

```
<pre>
  <code>var i = 0;</code>
  <code>var j = 0;</code>
<pre>
```

I've separate css for them: `pre{ ... }` and `code{ ... }`

Now, I want `<code>` style to be applied only if its parent isn't `<pre>`.

I've tried using `code:not(pre code){ ... }` but it didn't seem to work.

I can guarantee the HTML structure above.

Can it be solved through css?

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RXLpd/)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`:not(pre) > code { … }` should do the job, iff the `code` element is a *direct* child of the `pre` element.

Comment: That is highly inefficient, and will lag quite a bit if you have a lot of reflows on the page.

Comment: Perhaps, but what you suggest is hardly future proof.

Comment: @SecondRikudo My site is not going to be a code sharing or code intense one, and the structure of HTML can be guranteed. Will using this answer still have huge performance implications?

Comment: @Second Rikudo: Why is it highly inefficient? Given most implementations this at most adds an extra check to any existing `code` elements that are already being evaluated anyway.

Comment: Nope, it's completely valid, however, you don't know what the future might store.

Comment: Try it and see if it’s too slow. We cannot judge this without your complete structure and setup, browser and other specs. Profile profile profile.

Comment: @rightfold, It seems BoltClock's right. So, bravo to your answer. I can remove the `>` if it isn't direct child.

Comment: @Amit Joki: Actually, if it may not always occur as an immediate descendant, you'll end up with a whole new set of problems. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869061/is-the-css-not-selector-supposed-to-work-with-distant-descendants

Comment: @BoltClock, fortunately, It does occur as immediate descendant. BTW, HTH do you know the internals of CSS? Are you kinda a part of CSS spec team?

Comment: @Amit Joki: Nope, wish I was though. I just have an uncanny talent for understanding the CSS spec I guess.

Comment: you sure have @BoltClock.

Answer (score 6):

There is no parent selector in CSS. Your only choice is to make style that apply for both for the ones without the `<pre>` parent, and **override** those rules with the `<pre>` selector:

```
code { color: red; }
pre code { color: blue; } /* More specific, so will override the first! */
```

Alternative solutions include JavaScript.

Comment: The question does not call for a parent selector; rather, a child selector (like `pre code`). And there is a direct solution, described by @rightfold. However, the workaround suggested here has some benefits, like comprehensive browser support (as opposite to almost comprehensive) and the possibility of using both child and descendant selectors (e.g. `pre > code` or `pre code`). On the other hand, it requires that some explicit setting be used for those `code` elements that are not inside `pre` elements.