# Angularjs Protractor: Valid Selector for excluding nested elements

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors, protractor, nested-lists

I want to query on particular elements.

My structure for code is as below:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="main">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>
        <ul class="to--exclude">
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>...</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

I want to test `li's` presence inside 'main`class but not for`li's`which are inside`to-exclude` class.

The problem is if I use `element(by.css('.main li'))`, it will locate all the `li's` including the ones inside the `to-exclude` class.

In **Chrome's developer tools**, I'm able to locate them exactly using JQuery's `:not` or `.not()`.

```
$('.main li').not('ul.to--exclude li')
// OR
$(".main li:not('ul.to-exclude li')");
```

While using it in **protractor** as

```
element(by.css('.main li').not('ul.to--exclude li'));
// OR
element(by.css(".main li:not('ul.to--exclude li')"));
```

The above code gives an error:

```
InvalidElementStateError: invalid element state: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '.main li:not('ul.to--exclude li')' is not a valid selector.
```

How to accomplish the same in protractor. How to exclude some classes which are nested inside the parent locator class.

Thanks

Comment: jQuery `:not()` is different from CSS `:not()` - see [Why is my jQuery :not() selector not working in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/why-is-my-jquery-not-selector-not-working-in-css)

Comment: Also note that your HTML is invalid, you cannot have a `ul` directly within a `ul`. To nest lists you must have a `ul` within a `li`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do that with the CSS pseudo-class `:not` like this:

```
element(by.css(".main > li > ul:not(.to--exclude) li, .main > li)"));
```

I would add `.main > li` as a backup selector as it seems that you want to select all child `li`s under `.main`. This selector makes sense for such cases:

```html
<ul class="main">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>
        <ul class="to--exclude">
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="to--include">
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

If you don't have other `ul`s like `.to--include` you could reduce the selector to:

```
element(by.css(".main > li)"));
```

Comment: Note that this assumes the `ul` elements will only nest up to one level deep. If you have any more nested `ul` elements you will not be able to use `:not()` to filter them - see [Is the CSS :not() selector supposed to work with distant descendants?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869061/is-the-css-not-selector-supposed-to-work-with-distant-descendants)