# Exclude element with special parent using CSS selectors

Tags: css-selectors, jsoup

```html
<div class="exclude myclass moreclass">
    <div>
        <a href=""></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="otherclass">
  <a href=""></a>
</div>
<div class="myclass">
  <a href=""></a>
</div>
```

I need to select all the `<a>` elements that do not have ancestors (several levels up) with class `"exclude"`. How can I do it with jsoup?

Comment: Hmm...can't you do the opposite ? Apply a style to all links, and re-apply your "normal" style to descendants of "exclude".

Because you could try to do something like : `div:not(.exclude) a {color :red;}`. But since the `<a>` you are targeting *also* have `<div>` ancestors without your "exclude" class, it will not work.


You would do something like : `a {color:blue}` and `div.exclude a {color:red !important}`.

Answer (score 2):

With selectors, this is a non-trivial problem, especially if you start from the `<a>` elements and work your way up. Due to the nature of descendant selectors, [using `:not()` with descendant selectors does not always work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869061/is-the-css-not-selector-supposed-to-work-with-distant-descendants). In other words, something like

```
doc.select("div:not(.exclude) a");
```

won't work because in your first example, your intermediate classless `<div>` is `:not(.exclude)`, and for the rest of your elements any `<div>` elements higher up may also match `:not(.exclude)`.

One very simple workaround is to do it in two separate steps, which means using two separate selectors:

1. Select all `<a>` elements.
2. Then, manually exclude the ones that *do* have an ancestor with the specific class.

In CSS, this is achieved using an overriding rule. In jsoup, you use the `not()` method (note: this is different from the `:not()` pseudo-class in that the latter doesn't currently accept complex selectors unless jsoup implements it differently):

```
doc.select("a").not(".exclude a");
```

If you're being restricted to a single selector for whatever reason, then you may be in a fix. You will have to look at the HTML you're working with and see if you can construct a selector based on the information you have about the structure of the HTML. For example, you can look at the parent(s) *of* those elements that may have the class `exclude`. Will the class only appear on these top-level `<div>` elements that share the same parent? If so, you can use a child selector to anchor the `:not(.exclude)` to the parent:

```
doc.select("#parent > div:not(.exclude) a");
```

Although a descendant selector is still used to locate the `<a>` element from `div:not(.exclude)`, it will never match the classless element because the classless element is not a child of this hypothetical parent element.

If you cannot make *any* assumptions based on the structure about where the `exclude` class may appear, *and* you can't exclude the undesired elements separately, then there isn't much of a solution to this problem.