# CSS selector for something not inside something else

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have some nested elements like this:

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="select-inside-this">
        <div class="not-inside-this">
            <div class="one select-this"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="select-inside-this">
    <div class="two select-this"></div>
</div>
<div class="three select-this"></div>
```

I want to select all `.select-this` which are inside `.select-inside-this` but not those which are wrapped in `.not-inside-this`. So in the end, i should be able to select only `two.select-this` from the above code.
The CSS I've tried but did not work:

```
.select-inside-this :not(.not-inside-this) .select-this {
    /* style here /*
}
```

or:

```
.select-inside-this *:not(.not-inside-this) .select-this {
    /* style here /*
}
```

Any workaround here?

I don't want to use JavaScript here. I need pure CSS3 solution.

EDIT: I don't want to use direct child (`>`) selector. As I've asked, I want to select all those element from any level just without the exception wrapper.

Comment: The reason you can not use `.select-inside-this :not(.not-inside-this) .select-this` to select the required `.two.select-this` element here, is that `:not(.not-inside-this)` still needs to match an element for the whole selector to match (just _any_ element that does _not_ posses a certain characteristic) – but there is no element whatsoever between `.select-inside-this` and `.select-this` that could satisfy this, and therefor the whole selector _can not match_ this element.

Comment: That makes sense. But why `.select-inside-this *:not(.not-inside-this) .select-this doesn't` work?

Comment: Because it is basically the same thing. `*:not()` or `:not()`, that makes no difference whatsoever, both select _any_ element that does _not_ have the specified characteristic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is old question, but I had a similar problem and was able to solve it now with:

```
.select-inside-this .select-this:not(.not-inside-this *)
```

https://www.stefanjudis.com/snippets/how-to-select-elements-that-are-not-children-of-other-elements-in-css/

Comment: Exactly what I needed. `main ul:not(section *)` -> `inside MAIN, select an UL which isn't contained by a SECTION`.

Answer (score 38):

`:not(.not-inside-this)` and `*:not(.not-inside-this)` with the `*` are equivalent; in the case of the former, the universal selector is implied. See the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#universal-selector).

It is currently not possible to construct a CSS selector that matches elements that *are not descendants of* specific elements for the reasons given in the following questions:

- [CSS negation pseudo-class :not() for parent/ancestor elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084112/css-negation-pseudo-class-not-for-parent-ancestor-elements)
- [Is the CSS :not() selector supposed to work with distant descendants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869061/is-the-css-not-selector-supposed-to-work-with-distant-descendants)

The selector

```
.select-inside-this :not(.not-inside-this) .select-this
```

matches `.select-this` elements that *are* descendants of some element that *is not `.not-inside-this`*, which in turn is a descendant of `.select-inside-this`. It does *not* match `.select-this` elements that *are not descendants of `.not-inside-this`* within `.select-inside-this`.

This means, first off, that your selector will incorrectly match the following:

```
<div class="select-inside-this">
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="not-inside-this">
            <div class="select-this"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

... because one of the ancestors of `.select-this`, `.bar`, is `:not(.not-inside-this)`.

Additionally, this implies at least three levels of nesting (though it could be more). In your example, there are no other elements between `.two.select-this` and its containing `.select-inside-this`, so it will never match that element. This is why James Donnelly suggests adding `.select-inside-this > .select-this` to account for that particular case.

However it is still not possible to write a single complex selector using descendant combinators to match elements without a specific ancestor. The *only* way is to repeat the child combinator method with as many `:not(.not-inside-this)` as necessary, but this requires that you account for all possible cases. If you *can't* do that, then you're out of luck with CSS selectors.

Comment: @Abram: My answer does not describe a solution to begin with, so I'm not quite understanding what you're referring to as not working.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [Child Combinator Selector `>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators) to specify direct children:

```css
.select-inside-this :not(.not-inside-this) .select-this,
.select-inside-this > .select-this {
    /* style here /*
}
```

This selects any `.select-this` element which is not a descendent of any `.not-inside-this` element and also selects `.select-this` elements which are direct children of `.select-inside-this` elements.

```css
body > .select-inside-this :not(.not-inside-this) .select-this,
body > .select-inside-this > .select-this {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
    <div class="select-inside-this">
        <div class="not-inside-this">
            <div class="one select-this">
                This should not be selected
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="select-inside-this">
    <div class="two select-this">
        This should be selected
    </div>
</div>
<div class="three select-this">
    This should not be selected
</div>
```

Comment: I know that I could do that. But what I really need is to select from ancestor. That's why I've asked the question ;)

Answer (score 4):

A little bit late to the party, and it might not match your use case, but this is what I ended up doing:

HTML:

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="select-inside-this">
        <div class="not-inside-this">
            <div class="one select-this"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="select-inside-this">
    <div class="two select-this"></div>
</div>
<div class="three select-this"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.select-inside-this .select-this {
    background: blue;
}
.select-inside-this .not-inside-this .select-this {
    background: none;
}
```

The trick is to positively select the negative element and just undo the style.

It'll work for simple use cases, at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up

1. styling but hiding the styles by default, and then
2. revealing them on the nested element only.

Example with image backgrounds:

```
.box{
  height:100px;
  background-image: url("img.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top 100px left 0; /*hide by default (here by shifting position)*/ 
}
.container .box{
  background-position: top left; /*reveal in the nested*/
}
```

Hope you find a way to hide the style you need in place in a similar way.