# Select `td` in rows that are only inside a root table but not inside nested tables

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a table that can contain nested tables which renders inside a drawer.
The nested table is the same component, and i'm trying to create a css selector that will select the `td` elements of rows of the root table and not of nested tables.

I have started with the following selector:

```js
table.querySelectorAll(`tbody tr > td:nth-child(${index + 1})`)
```

It indeed selected the right td elements but from all the rows of all tables. I should note that the nested table is within a div that has `[data-state="open"]` but it didn't help me so far. The only way i'm thinking on how to determine a row from nested row is that it has 1 parent table element instead of 2.

Thanks

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52348485/queryselectorall-and-not) might help. If you use attribute for non nested table td you will be able to use the :not() selector

Comment: `tbody tr` in your selector of course allows for _any_ amount of elements to come between those two; but there is a problem before that already - `table.querySelectorAll('tbody')` already gets you _all_ tbodies inside of that table, no matter what level they are on. You can not use this to select only tbodies that are _children_ of `table` here, since you can not use `>` at the start of a selector. [...]

Comment: [...] If you don't want to further filter your elements afterwards, then you need to "include" the table in the selector already here - you'd need some selector to uniquely identify the table (such as an ID, maybe dynamically set), `#specificTable > tbody > tr > ...`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:not` selector

```
td:not(tbody tbody td)
```

```css
td {
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background: lightblue;
}

td:not(tbody tbody td) {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is great! it does select only the root table rows. but now when I'm trying to select the nested drawer rows it doesn't select them. for context, i'm painting the rows when i'm resizing a column.
So with this new selector, it finds the rows of the root table when resizing one of its columns correctly, but when trying to resize a column in the nested table, it finds none.

Comment: Don’t you need to drop the :not to get to the nested tds. What selectors are you using?

Comment: A brief [mcve] of the *actual* issue is required here. Quite likely that is a *separate* question though.

Comment: A further caveat: the selector in this answer does indeed select just the outer table's tds. However, if you then go on so say set some inheritable property, like color, then that will be taken up by the inner elements - so making it look as tho' they too have been selected. Hence the need for an explicit setting for all tds as in this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Modifid answer:
Select all existing TDs then filter those are not direct children of the root table:

```
const rootTable = document.querySelector('table');
const allTdElements = rootTable.querySelectorAll('td');

const rootTableTdElements = Array.from(allTdElements).filter(td => {
    //Exclude TDs which are not direct children of the root table
    return td.closest('table') === rootTable;
});
```

*Old answer which selects all TDs without filtering:*

> *To choose direct children you can use `>` which is direct child
> selector:*
>
> ```
> table.querySelectorAll(`tbody > tr > td:nth-child(${index + 1})`);
> ```

Comment: this still won't work, because the nested table has the same hierarchy.
`tr > table > tbody > tr > td`