# Select all elements but not in parent with specific class

Tags: html, css

I have following scenario and I can't figure out how to select all `p` elements but not in `div` with `content` class:

```
<div class="content">
  <p></p> <!-- not this one -->
  <p></p> <!-- not this one -->
  <div>
   <p></p> <!-- not this one because this is also inside content -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="other">
  <p></p> <!--this one -->
</div>
<p></p> <!--this one -->
```

So I just want to select all `p` elements but not elements inside element with `class="content"`.

More info:
I have application that content is dynamically generated. In this content there are some `p` elements that I don't want to apply the styles.

Some brilliant developer add this kind of style in the beginning of the project:

```
p {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 12px!important;
  line-height: 18px!important;
  margin: 0!important;
}
```

So as You see this applies to all `p` elements. My task is to fix only `content` rendering so it will have different font-size etc... So I though I will change p selector to exclude those inside `content` class. If I change this definition of `p` css style then I can unintentionally change some other subpage so I don't want to mess with that because I just want to make it fast without going deep into the code and html created by this developer. The rest of the page is working fortunately very well but I don't know how to nail all those elements in `content` class only and leaving the rest of `p` elements as it was untouched.

Comment: dp the opposite and select all the `p` you don't want and disable the CSS you want to apply for the other

Comment: The answer is - you can't. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268382/css-selector-for-something-not-inside-something-else

Comment: you can using NOT selector like this.   :not(.content) p{
    /* Styles */
}

Comment: I made an edit to my answer trying to address the edit you made on your question, check it

Comment: @Marcin Kapusta please check below answer !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select all `p` tags and then add a CSS style to the ones that you don't want to select, in this case `.content p`.
See below code with this idea.

But, if possible, add a common class to the `p` that you want to select or a common class to the `p` that you don't want to select, it would be much more controllable.

**EDIT**
Since you eddited the question explaining that you have `p` styled with `!important` values and don't want to change, I made an edit here to try to fix the `p` that is inside `.content`. You'll need to force `!important` there too, modifying the values to `unset` (or other value that you want) check it:

```css
p {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  line-height: 18px !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.content p{
  color: unset !important;
  font-size: initial !important;
  line-height: 25px !important;
  margin: initial !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>1</p>
  <!-- not this one -->
  <p>2</p>
  <!-- not this one -->
  <div>
    <p>3</p>
    <!-- not this one because this is also inside content -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="other">
  <p>4</p>
  <!--this one -->
</div>
<p>5</p>
<!--this one -->
```

Comment: with due respect i think we can make it better without using `!important`. Thank you !

Comment: of course, `!important` is not a good solution, but based on what OP said *"...If I change this definition of p css style then I can unintentionally change some other subpage so I don't want to mess ..."* he don't want to change `p` selector, so he will keep the `!important` there, creating the need to use the same technique on any other `p` selectors that may be conflict with this one

Comment: Thanks @CalvinNunes. This is exactly what I was looking for to solve this not usual use case. Thank You very much for Your time to read my question and situation around it. I was not aware that `!important` can be overridden by specify more detailed selector. New lesson learnt. Thank You Man! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think simplest way to do that code for `.content p` to be on the top of the `p` as in below, no need to use of important.

```css
.content p{
  color: red;
  font-size: 24px;
}
p {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>1</p>
  <!-- not this one -->
  <p>2</p>
  <!-- not this one -->
  <div>
    <p>3</p>
    <!-- not this one because this is also inside content -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="other">
  <p>4</p>
  <!--this one -->
</div>
<p>5</p>
<!--this one -->
```