# CSS select all select2 where the parent is not under a table

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-select2

Hi all I modify my select2 with this code

```
.select2-selection {
  height: 200px!important;
}
```

however I do not want to modify select2 that are inside my datatable plugin. From inspecting the element I notice that the select2 in datatable was under the th span span select2-selection .

So I tired this code to change all select2 height that are not in tr tag but it is still changing the height of the select2 in the datatable.

How do I make it only change the height that are not in a table? Much help would be appreciated

```
:not(th) > .select2-selection {
  height: 100px!important;
}
```

also tried

```
  :not(th) .select2-selection {
      height: 100px!important;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS selector for something not inside something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268382/css-selector-for-something-not-inside-something-else)

Comment: Hi yeah I read that (check edits the guy did what I did) but it still did not work. Maybe it's cause select2 or something

Comment: The accepted answer to that question is, essentially, "there is no way of doing that", so I'm not sure what you're talking about.