# Css selector not, not working for anchors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I cannot understand the reason, but checking in chrome, it seems like using the :not selector is not working with a tag. Does anyone understand the reason?

Here is an example codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PQezVB

```
:not(a){
   color:blue;
}
```

Comment: see the codepen, it doesn't work

Comment: The reason is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869061/is-the-css-not-selector-supposed-to-work-with-distant-descendants), and these are fundamentally the same thing, but I'm hesitant to mark this as a duplicate since it doesn't involve a descendant combinator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The :not(selector) selector matches every element that is NOT the specified element/selector.
>   The :not() CSS pseudo-class represents elements that do not match a list of selectors. Since it prevents specific items from being selected, it is known as the negation pseudo-class.

So to use it you should specify the css of the element that is then use `not` for those how don't

```css
*:not(a){
   color:blue;
}
* {
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
<span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</span>
<i>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</i>
<h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h1>
<a>This is the link "a tag"</a>
```

Comment: Why is the `*` rule required? The rule that colors things blue shouldn't affect the link at all.

Comment: wrong if you remove * the link would be blue , cuze the text inside it @HubertGrzeskowiak

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, it should be used like this:

```
p {
    color: initial;
}

:not(p) {
    color: green;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XZqKwd

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here: [Is the CSS :not() selector supposed to work with distant descendants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869061/is-the-css-not-selector-supposed-to-work-with-distant-descendants)

Basically by selecting everything but the element you also select its parent elements and hence it's colored as well from inheritance.

```
:not(a) { color: red; }
```

in this case is almost equivalent to:

```
* { color: red; } /* includes "body" element etc. */
a { color: inherit; }
```

Comment: That's why I'm thinking this is a duplicate, even if it doesn't necessarily involve the descendant combinator. There doesn't appear to be any good way to phrase this generally in a question, though.

Answer (score -2):

Adding "href" attribute to the anchor tag seems to solve this issue.

```html
<p>Hello world</p>
<a href="">Some link</a>
```