# Apply CSS to any element except for certain class descendants?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to apply certain CSS to any element, except descendants of a certain class?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/68jgdthm

As you can see I want everything on the page to be `dark` except elements which are descendants of the `light` class. The trick here is that one can't know if the element is a direct descendant, e.g. it might be this:

```
<div class="light">
  <p>Element</p>
</div>
```

but it might also be this:

```
<div class="light">
  <div>
    <div>
      <p>Element</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `dark` class is almost always added to the `body` element and will always be a parent of any `light` classes.

One might say:

- *Just make the body "light" and add `dark` classes to any elements you need.* - But I actually need the opposite, I need everything to be `dark` and certain elements to be `light`.
- *Then add "light" styles and add the `light` class to elements you need.* - I already have the `dark` styles, so I'm looking for an easier "excluding" solution (I'm using LESS, so prefixing etc. is quite easy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to exclude descendants this way without writing a separate selector. You won't be able to do this even using `:not()`, for the reasons stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540708/why-doesnt-this-css-not-declaration-filter-down).

Fortunately, the fact that `.light` elements will only ever occur within the context of a `.dark` element and *not vice versa* makes this a little easier. Since you have a `body` CSS rule already, just add `.light p` to that rule, and move the entire ruleset underneath `.dark p` so `.light p` will take precedence:

```
.dark p {
    color: #000;
}

body, .light p {
    color: #ccc;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/68jgdthm/2)

Alternatively if you want to keep the `body` rule on top, you could bump up the specificity of `.light p` to ensure it will take precedence:

```
body, body .light p {
    color: #ccc;
}

.dark p {
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is good, although I will still have to "write" separate declarations for the `light` and `dark` styles, since `p` usually has it's own styles for the light version, which aren't just inherited from the `body`. At least now I know why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

Color is an inherited property. Therefore just by declaring `.dark` and `.light` to have the wanted color is a good thing. You can make a default by assigning it to the body. I think atomic design like this is a good practice, as you don't add too much specificity in your CSS.

You could do this:

```
body {
    color: #ccc;
}
.dark {
    color: #000;
}
.light {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/68jgdthm/1/

Comment: Yes, I know, but that is exactly the thing I'm trying to avoid - writing redundant code.

Comment: Why is this redundant?

Comment: @Sampsa Why do you need `*` since `color` is inherited?

Comment: @torazaburo: That's what I thought as well. In the end, when writing my answer I decided not to assume that `color` was the only property the OP had to deal with.

Comment: It isn't redundant if it does the job you want done!

Comment: Yup, the `*` is not needed. It was just to clarify that these things inherit. I think atomic design like `.dark` and `.light` are good, and that's why I said it was a bit nasty. I edited my answer to be more clear.