# How to target a selector only if it's NOT child of a specific element (so only if it's the root)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I don't understand why the following code has not desired behaviour:

```css
    .toggle {
      color: red;
    }
    
    :not(.list) .toggle {
      font-weight:bold;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
      <a href="#!" class="toggle">Toggle</a>
      <ul class="list">
        <li><a href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
        <li>
          <div class="container">
            <a href="#!" class="toggle">SubToggle</a>
            <ul class="list">
              <li><a href="#!">SubLink 1</a></li>
              <li>
                <a href="#!">SubLink 2</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#!">SubLink 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

I thought that using `:not()` would result in applying "bold" only to main "Toggle" link but instead it applis "bold" to all of red ones. Why?

*Please, note that this code is nested with same class names, I don't want to target specific levels with different css classes, I would like to target elements only with descendant selectors and other operators*

Here is present also a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ldetomi/s249tyur/) to directly try.

Comment: you try to do this? https://jsfiddle.net/zeevkatz/1yy72grr/1/

Comment: @LucaDetomi: This is a known behavior. It happens because the second toggle's (the Sub toggle) immediate parent also doesn't have `class='list'` so that also applies the `:not(.list) .toggle`.

Comment: @Harry Yes, it's true, but your description would convince me if I wrote a direct child selector using `>`. Here I don't specify how deep is hierarchy to find (or not find) `.list` class

Comment: @ZeevKatz Yes, I tried and it's my actual solution, but I would like to avoid (if possible) to override internal elements because in real case there are many CSS properties to be overridden, not only `font-weight` (this is only a simplified exampe)

Comment: @LucaDetomi: See `:not(.list) .toggle` would select all .toggle who are not descendants of `.list`. You have a clash. The outermost has but the `body` doesn't, and the inner one doesn't too. So which one do you want CSS to consider as the ancestor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35051671/cascading-with-css-not-pseudo-class/35051684#35051684 I am hesitant to close only because you want a workaround which doesn't include targetting each level separately.

Comment: @Harry The `body > element` selector indeed resolved my particular issue at hand.

Answer (score 5):

I think you might want this:

```
.toggle {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div *:not(.list) .toggle {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: The result it the opposite of what desired. It's the main Toggle that should be "bold"

Answer (score 3):

`:not` does not support CSS Combinators.

**Your only way to do this is:**

```
.toggle {
  color: red;
}

.toggle {
  font-weight:bold;
}

.list .toggle {
  /* Override previous */
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zeevkatz/1yy72grr/)

Comment: Not strictly true. There is nothing in the RFC about not supporting combinators. While `:not(.class) .otherClass` does not work, `:not(.class) > .otherClass` works fine. Here's proof: https://jsfiddle.net/k0m7512j/  However, in the circumstances OP presented, your answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

I tried so many times but this is the only way I can do:

```
.toggle {
  color: red;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.list .toggle{
  //override
  font-weight:normal;
}
```

This is how to use :not the right way:
add `specialToggle` for elements you `do not want to select`

```
<a href="#!" class="toggle specialToggle">SubToggle</a>
```

and then css:

```
.toggle {
  color: red;
}

.toggle:not(.specialToggle) {
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s249tyur/3/

Answer (score 1):

If the structure is always going to be the same you could try using the greater-than sign (>), it means only apply the style to the immediate children of the class.

```
.container > .toggle {
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Or if the container is not always going to have the same class, but is always a div element you could use:

```
div > .toggle {
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Please don't call a greater-than sign a chevron. > is not the same as  ›. The situation on this site is bad enough as it is, with people using less-than and greater-than signs as chevrons, making the words inbetween come out invisible.

Comment: Edited, thank you, i was not aware that it was an issue to used to using the terms around the office.

Comment: Well, the issue is that people use them as quotation marks in posts here, and the system handles them as HTML tags. So e.g. people write "I hit <Ctrl> <Alt> <Delete>" and it comes out as "I hit " because unknown HTML tags are ignored.

Comment: **greater-than sign (>) only selects immediate children** - This saved my day. Thanks!