# Does css3's :not() only work on direct children?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to use css3's `:not()` selector to select certain elements that do not have a parent element with a certain class anywhere as its ancestor.

The mark up is simple:

```
<div><strong><em>Please select me!</em></strong></div>

<div><strong><p><em>Please don't select me!</em></p></strong></div>

<div><p><em>Please don't select me!</em></p></div>
```

And this is the selector I am using: `div *:not(p) em`.

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cwxzH/

Why is the second `div` being selected if I am filtering out all children of the `div` that are `paragraphs`? Is there anyway to prevent this?

I have only tested in IE9 and FF13 so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div *` selects all descendants of div ie `strong` `p` `em` then the `:not(p)` removes the `p` so you're left with `strong` and `em`, now with the `em` only the `strong` has an `em` descendant(the `em`) resulting in the `em` getting selected on the second `div`

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. Is there anyway to work around this and only select the first `em` in the first `div`?

Comment: @phpdev: Not really, no. You cannot reliably use `:not()` for filtering ancestor elements - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084112/css-negation-pseudo-class-not-for-parent-ancestor-elements

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for? It selects all `em` elements that are not direct children of paragraphs:

```
div :not(p)>em
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cwxzH/1/

Comment: Is there anyway to select ALL `em`s except ones where there they have a `p` ancestor or parent?

Comment: The code I posted selects all ems except ones that have a *parent* p. As for *ancestors* on any level, I don't think so, because `:not` would still select any element between the p and the em.