# Select all siblings if one of them has a specific class

Tags: html, css

**RE: above regarding duplicate** - my question asks if there was a way to select ALL elements inside of a child where one class exists in pure CSS whereas that linked question is just asking if there is an opposite of the `+` selector which is not what I was asking/looking for. This should be untagged as duplicate.

**Main Question:**

I want to select all elements inside a parent if one of the siblings has a specific class. How do I do this? I tried:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp

> The element1~element2 selector matches occurrences of element2 that
>   are preceded by element1.

But it's not what I want.

[CSS sibling selectors (select all siblings)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813465/css-sibling-selectors-select-all-siblings)

My question is not a duplicate as the class is in the first element in above question comes first which makes it work.

See below:

```css
.red ~ .item {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="item red">list item</li>
<li class="item">list item</li>
<li class="item">list item</li>
<li class="item">list item</li>
<ul>

<ul>
<li class="item">list item</li>
<li class="item">list item</li>
<li class="item red">list item</li>
<li class="item">list item</li>
<ul>
```

How do you select all siblings if one of them has a class in pure CSS? Or do I need to use JS?

Comment: You can use JavaScript for this

Comment: You'd *have* to use JavaScript for this since CSS has no previous sibling selector.

Comment: @j08691 ok good to know, thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector

Comment: why did this get marked duplicate and downvoted? I was asking if there was a way to select ALL elements where one class exists in a child and that question just asks if there is a previous selector. Is there a way to dispute this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery to get the siblings and then apply the `red` class to them.

```js
$( "li.item.red" ).siblings().addClass("red");
```

```css
.red {
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="item red">list item</li>
<li class="item">list item</li>
<li class="item">list item</li>
<li class="item">list item</li>
<ul>

<ul>
<li class="item">list item</li>
<li class="item">list item</li>
<li class="item red">list item</li>
<li class="item">list item</li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

For this particular case and if you want to apply background to all your elements, you can consider a pseudo element that will cover all of them as your background layer:

```css
ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.red:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 40px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item red">list item</li>
  <li class="item">list item</li>
  <li class="item">list item</li>
  <li class="item">list item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="item">list item</li>
  <li class="item">list item</li>
  <li class="item red">list item</li>
  <li class="item">list item</li>
</ul>
```