# What does the + :not() mean in this case?

Tags: html, css

there I am bothered by what is this `+` and `:not()` selector. This is not my code, but I want to understand it. What does this mean?

```
   .chat-segment-sent {
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 0 .5rem 3rem;
  }
 
 .chat-segment-sent.chat-start .chat-message {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px; 
  }

  .chat-segment-sent.chat-start + :not(.chat-end) .chat-message {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px; 
  }

  .chat-segment-sent.chat-end .chat-message {
    border-top-right-radius: 3px; 
  }

  .chat-segment-sent .chat-message {
    background: #1dc9b7;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
  }
```

The arrangement of the blocks looks like this:

```
chat-segment chat-segment-get/send chat-start
     chat-message /
/
chat-segment chat-segment-get/send
     chat-message /
/
chat-segment chat-segment-get/send chat-end
     chat-message /
/
```

The issue is that I need to repair that code. When I add another middle sector, border-radius does not apply to this new block.

So there is my second question how can I start to think about repairing that code, for proper behaviour?

Comment: `+` - https://stackoverflow.com/q/1139763/3001761

Comment: yes but with combination with not() is that somekind of - until something - meaning?

Comment: `:not(<selector>)` is a pseudo selector, meaning what it says on the tin - an element *not* matching the `<selector>`. In this case, an adjacent element that doesn't have the class of `chat-end`.

Comment: yeah it should to everything below that is not chat-end, yet the second question remain unsolved, how can i add infinite number of plusses, not only one below div.... until  chat-end

as i understant it aplied only to the next block that is not chat-end,but i need next and next and next if there is any

Comment: Then maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/q/11813465/3001761

Comment: Thank you, it is working that is the thing i was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

While the comments below your question give you links to useful resources for the theory, here is the practical:

```
 .chat-segment-sent.chat-start + :not(.chat-end) .chat-message {
```

Means:

- Select the element that contains both `chat-segment-sent` and `chat-start` classes
- Which is then immediately followed by a peer (non parent non child) element (of/with any class/id) which is *not* marked as a `chat-end` class.
- And then focus on the element with the `chat-message` class that is a child of the above *peer element*.

Resources:

- [What does the "+" (plus sign) CSS selector mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1139763/3001761)
- [What does this symbol mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39710045/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-css)

Example:

```css
.chat-segment-sent.chat-start + :not(.chat-end) .chat-message {
    color:green;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='chat-segment-sent chat-start'>
<div class='chat-message'>
  Hello 1
  </div>
</div>
<div class='chat-segment-sent chat-start'>
<div class='chat-message'>
  Hello 2
  </div>
</div>
<div class='chat-segment-sent chat-start'>
<div class='chat-message'>
  Hello 3
  </div>
</div>
<div class='chat-segment-sent chat-start'>
<div class='chat-message'>
  Hello 4
  </div>
</div>
<div class='chat-segment-sent chat-start'>
<div class='chat-message'>
  Hello 5
  </div>
</div>
<div class='chat-segment-sent chat-start chat-end'>
   <div class='chat-message'>END</div>
</div>
<div class='chat-segment-sent chat-start'>
<div class='chat-message'>
  Hello bonus
  </div>
</div>
<div class='chat-somethingelse'>
<div class='chat-message'>
  this element is highlighed because it is a sibling which does not contain the chat-end class.  
  </div>
</div>
<div class='chat-somethingelse chat-end'>
<div class='chat-message'>
  this element is not highlighted because it is a sibling but it does contain the chat-end class.  
  </div>
  <div>
     this element is not highlighted because it is not a neighbouring sibling. 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, but this is only applied to one element after? or to the many elements that is not a 'chat-end' class? Another question would be, how to applied it to many blocks followed by a peer that are not 'chat-end' is that even possible?

Comment: this site contain this code, you can test it here:
https://www.gotbootstrap.com/themes/smartadmin/4.5.0/intel_analytics_dashboard.html
 - the chat with this code is clickable on the planet in the header on the right side of the page

Comment: however another one question i have, but maybe on the end.

Comment: i starting to understand it but is there a way to aplied to all the siblings not only to the next one?

Comment: @ActionMan I have updated my answer. The CSS applies to all siblings that fit the criteria and that do not contain the `.chat-end` class

Comment: that is not true, only to the next one

Comment: @ActionMan what you're looking for is something different. What you asked is how something works, if you want to ask about a specific solution to a specific criteria please ask a new question. Thanks

Comment: thank you, i am still learning stack overflow, ill do that