# How to only select this class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How would I only select the `.media` class that is NOT a child of the `.slideshow` class?

```
<article>
    <div class="entry"></div>
    <figure class="media"></figure>
</article>

<article>
    <div class="slideshow">
        <div class="entry"></div>
        <figure class="media"></figure>
    </div>
</article>
```

Obviously I can do `.slideshow .media` to target the second one, but how would I target that first one?

NOTE: There are multiples of each of these blocks, so just doing something like `article:first-chlid` to select the first instance wouldn't work.

Example of multiple blocks...

```
<article>
    <div class="entry"></div>
    <figure class="media"></figure>
</article>

<article>
    <div class="entry"></div>
    <figure class="media"></figure>
</article>

<article>
    <div class="entry"></div>
    <figure class="media"></figure>
</article>

<article>
    <div class="slideshow">
        <div class="entry"></div>
        <figure class="media"></figure>
    </div>
</article>

<article>
    <div class="entry"></div>
    <figure class="media"></figure>
</article>

<article>
    <div class="slideshow">
        <div class="entry"></div>
        <figure class="media"></figure>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Can you show what the multiples of these blocks would look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They don't mean the exact same thing, so I would add a second class to the `class=media` part so you can target it separately

```
<article>
    <div class="entry"></div>
    <figure class="media"></figure>
</article>

<article>
    <div class="slideshow">
        <div class="entry"></div>
        <figure class="media another-class"></figure>
    </div>
</article>
```

**CSS**

```
.media.another-class {...}
```

You could also use the immediate child selector

```
article > .media
```

Answer (score 6):

You could just use two classes...

```
.media{
  /* styles here */
  padding:10px;
}
.slideshow .media{
  /* styles here */
  padding:20px;
}
```

Comment: it depends on how the html is added, if you are using a CMS or something that is building the structure for you, this is easier... otherwise I like your method

Comment: That's backwards for what I want to do. Like I said, I know I can do `.slideshow .media` to select the second, but I need to select on that first one.

Comment: the point is that `.slideshow .media` is more specific and will override `.media`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
:not(.slideshow)>.media{
  //code here
}
```

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/kLyDF/

info:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp

Comment: Wish I could like this twice, I had completely forgotten about it... IE finally supports it, in the past I was unable to use it because of IE [compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)

Comment: Besides the oft-nagged issue of browser support, using `:not()` to exclude parents is very fragile; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084112/css-negation-pseudo-class-not-for-parent-ancestor-elements Given the markup, it is safe to assume that `article` is the only other parent that can be `:not(.slideshow)`.