# CSS Selection / Transition property value seems to be wrong

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-transitions

I used the `#footer a` selector before, but after removing `#footer` to make the change apply to all `<a>`'s on the page except the ones in a div with a class of `.navbar`, no links get the following selectors assigned: `a:not(.navbar a)`,`a:not(.navbar a):hover`, `a:not(.navbar a):active` (also seen in Google Chrome element inspector)

I created 2 snippets to represent what I'm trying to say:

1. Working example of first version

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: #3D64FF
}

#footer a {
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 0;
  transition: text-shadow 0.1s linear, padding 0.1s linear;
}

#footer a:hover {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #3D64FF;
  padding: 0 5px;
  transition: text-shadow 0.1s linear, padding 0.1s linear;
}

#footer a:active {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #3556DB;
  padding: 0 2px;
  transition: text-shadow 0.1s linear, padding 0.1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <a href="#">Footer link #1</a><br>
  <a href="#">Footer link #2</a><br>
  <a href="#">Footer link #3</a><br>
  <a href="#">Footer link #4</a>
</div>
```

2. Broken, new code

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: #3D64FF
}

a:not(.navbar a) {
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 0;
  transition: text-shadow 0.1s linear, padding 0.1s linear;
}

a:not(.navbar a):hover {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #3D64FF;
  padding: 0 5px;
  transition: text-shadow 0.1s linear, padding 0.1s linear;
}

a:not(.navbar a):active {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #3556DB;
  padding: 0 2px;
  transition: text-shadow 0.1s linear, padding 0.1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div calss="navbar"><a href="#">NAVBAR link</a></div>
<a href="#">Not NAVBAR link</a>
```

I have to fix it again, so it applies to the entire page, except that one div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do `a:not(.navbar a)` in CSS.

If you know your `a` will always be directly nested within `.navbar` and you want to exclude that `a`, you could select `:not(.navbar) > a` instead. But if the nesting level is arbitrary and you want to exclude `a` nested anywhere within `.navbar`, then you'll probably have trouble writing a CSS selector for that. Something like `:not(.navbar) a` can always match some other element higher up in the tree. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084112/css-negation-pseudo-class-not-for-parent-ancestor-elements/7084147#7084147) for another example of why it won't work.

The simplest solution to this is to apply the effects to all `a` elements, then undo them in `.navbar a`:

```
.navbar a {
  text-shadow:none;
  padding:0;
  -webkit-transition-property: none;
  -moz-transition-property: none;
  -o-transition-property: none;
  transition-property: none;
}
```

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/VJ43W/4)

Comment: Acoording to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/VJ43W/3/) fiddle, the selector now works, but it does not exclude the navbar. And the `<a>` can be in any element inside the `.navbar` (look in fiddle)

Comment: @DJDavid98: You can't do `:not(.navbar a)`. I wasn't clear on that, edited.

Comment: I can't, okay, but how do I achieve this then?

Comment: @DJDavid98: You simply want to disable transitions on `.navbar a` elements, right?

Comment: No, I want to disable transitions AND not apply the `padding` and `text-shadow` to them.

Comment: @DJDavid98: Which means when you hover on those links, nothing should happen?

Comment: On my live site, the menus look weird now.

Comment: Never mind. I decided to remove the padding, so it will work. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: @DJDavid98: Ah, OK. Glad you sorted it out!