# How to write this :not "in other element" CSS rule?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Here is the html layout

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="section">
        <span class="text">text1</span>
    </div>
    <span class="text">text2</span>
<span class="not-text">don't color me!</span>
</div>
```

Im trying to give a style to all "text" spans which are not in the "section" divs.
I tried this, but it doesn't seem to be working

```
.wrap :not(.section) .text
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4zns2/34/)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: There are several workarounds for this case including the use of > operator like in ".wrap > .text", but I would like to know how to make the :not selector working, to make use of it in the future

Comment: `.wrap > .text` will work, but that's cheating ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `.wrap :not(.section) .text`, this is what you're telling the browser:

1. Look for an element with a class of `.text`
2. which lives inside an element that does not have a class of `.section`
3. which lives inside
   an element that has a class of `.wrap`

If you look closely at your markup, none of your elements meet that selector criteria.

In the markup you provided, I don't think you can specifically select those `.text` elements that are not descendants of `.section` using `:not()`.

The closest you could get is by using a direct descendant selector, like this:

```
.wrap > .text
```

You could also select and style all `.text` descendants of `.wrap` (whether direct or not), and then cancel those styles for any `.text` elements inside of `.section`, like this:

```
.wrap .text {
  // your styles here
}

.wrap .section .text {
  // your cancelled styles here
}
```

Comment: This is how I break down complex selectors in my own answers as well. A different explanation of pretty much the same situation can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084112/css-negation-pseudo-class-not-for-parent-ancestor-elements/7084147#7084147). In short, using `:not()` with descendant selectors is unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use:

```
.wrap > span
.wrap > *:not(div)
.wrap > *:not(.section)
```

Comment: I meant them as separate things, not all at once. They would all do the same thing with the provided HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Best option given the constraints of CSS are to write a rule for all text and then override them back to the previous value for those within .section. So

```
.wrap .text {
   // the styles you want
}

.wrap .section .text {
  // styles undoing the styles above... depending on what the styles are it may not always be possible

}
```