# Why CSS :not pseudo-class doesn't work as expected?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">Hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    <div class="b">World</div>
</div>
```

Adding the following CSS colors only "World" in red, as expected:

```
.c .b {
  color: red;
}
```

But, adding the following CSS instead [colors both "Hello" and "World" in red](http://jsbin.com/odubod/3):

```
:not(.a) .b {
  color: red;
}
```

Why?

Comment: Using `:not()` to exclude parent elements is not reliable - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084112/css-negation-pseudo-class-not-for-parent-ancestor-elements/7084147#7084147

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to give it like this:-

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xHRqF/)

```
div:not(.a) .b {
  color: red;
}
```

[Pseudo-class :not](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3anot)

> Syntax is selector:not(){ properties }

Comment: The syntax does not actually *require* the `:not()` to be qualified by anything, but it's good practice anyway.

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock but looking at the syntax and examples in the documentation and trying without `:not(.a) .b` it did not make the appropriate selection atleast in Chrome. I have also used it this way myself.. Probably i am missing something.. :|

Comment: Yep, what I'm basically saying is that it works without the "selector" part but like you mentioned it doesn't do what you expect. Also see my comment link on the question.

Comment: @Mr Lister: Hm? They do handle both of them equivalently and according to spec...

Comment: @BoltClock Sorry, I had trouble looking beyond these answers, which turned out to be incorrect after all.

Answer (score 3):

Since the `:not` pseudo-class represents an element that is not represented by its argument,
you **have** to specify the element you want to exclude **before** the `:not` selector

Per your example, try this instead:

```
div:not(.a) .b {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: No... the argument is what's inside the parentheses - in this case it's `.a`, which you are excluding, not `div`, which is what you want to limit the selector to. Also see my comment on PSL's answer.