# blur all elements except one in a div

Tags: html, css, blur

I am trying to blur all elements in a div except one.
I have looked at many similar questions like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410675/why-css-not-pseudo-class-doesnt-work-as-expected) and I get this:

```
.table-responsive:not(.confirm) {
    filter: blur(3px);
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

This is basically supposed to blur all elements except the confirm class. Here is a js fiddle demonstrating it: https://jsfiddle.net/qbuyuhts/1/

It's some janky html but does the job to show the problem. Does anyone know why the .confirm div is blurring?

Comment: why not put  `.confirm` outside `.table-responsive` ?

Comment: well I am trying to do this for the whole body, so I just want to figure out why the :not selector doesnt work

Comment: Shouldn't the selector be `.table-responsive > *:not(.confirm)`? `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `.table-responsive:not(.confirm) {` selects element that have class `.table-responsive` and have not class `.confirm` this is wrong ,because `.confirm` is children of `.table-responsive`.

*So change your code like this:*

```
.table-responsive table, .table-responsive div:not(.confirm) {
    filter: blur(3px);
     pointer-events: none;
}
```

```css
.table-responsive table, .table-responsive div:not(.confirm) {
  filter: blur(3px);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div style="border: none; overflow-x: visible;" class="table-responsive">

  <div style="background-color:white; width:35%; position:absolute; left:34%;" class="confirm">
    <h3 style="color:black">Are you sure?</h3>
    <button style="background-color:black;color:blue">Cancel</button>
    <button style="background-color:black;color:blue">Confirm</button>
  </div>

  <table id="tbl" style="width:100%">
    <tbody style="display: block; overflow-y: auto">
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-right:1em"><a class="remove"><button>Remove</button></a></td>
        <td style="padding-right:1em"><a><button>Edit</button></a></td>
        <td class="coursetext"><h4 align="left"><b>{{ course }}</b><br><span class="tohide"><b>{{ sections }}</b></span></h4><hr></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
</div>
```