# Select all elements except children of class

Tags: css, css-selectors

How do I select all `<div>` elements except  the divs that are within elements with certain classes?

Tried:

```
 div :not(.test div)
 div:not(.test div)
```

but doesn't work!

---

### Edit:

Here is the HTML as requested.

```
<div>
</div>

<span class="test">
 <div/>
</span>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no space after div, so that the `:not` is related to it, then the second div is a child, so not a part of the `:not`

```
div:not(.test) div {
    /* style */
}
```

for

```
<div class="test">
    <div></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div></div> <!-- gets selected -->
</div>
```

Edit: when you added markup, the correct version would be

```
div :not(.test) div {
    /* style */
}
```

for

```
<div>
    <span class="test">
        <div></div>
    </span>
    <span>
        <div></div> <!-- gets selected -->
    </span>
</div>
```

or

```
span:not(.test) div {
    /* style */
}
```

for

```
<span class="test">
    <div></div>
</span>
<span>
    <div></div> <!-- gets selected -->
</span>
```

Because you haven't mention the `span` in the original question nor have you specified if the span itself was inside a div.

---

You should also consider using `>` in your selector in this case to narrow it down.

Comment: `:not(.test) div` is effectively the same as `div` in most cases because `:not(.test)` would still match `html`, `body` and any other higher ancestors unless all of them contained the same class. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084112/css-negation-pseudo-class-not-for-parent-ancestor-elements

Comment: @BoltClock yes, I realise that, added a footnote and will change the selector too

Comment: you listed two options one for div another for span, but what if I dont know which is there, how to generalise this ?

Comment: To generalise: `:not` should have space in front only if it is not linked to the element before it: `div :not(.test)`  checks for a child without class `.test`. The brackets are whats tested, do `:not(.test) div` is for a div-child of an element without `.test`.

Comment: if you could, please edit the css section in this fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/pMrkW/] to end all the doubts.

Comment: ohk.. but this works only when `div` is enclosed within `span`. See here .. http://jsfiddle.net/pMrkW/3/ Couldn't get a generalized solution.