# Sass, invert selection

Tags: css, sass

I was thinking of using something like this but it doesn't listen to me. 
Wanted to exclude the 'div' that has 'headline-5' as parent / Any thoughs?

Thanks

```
div {
  @media #{$default} {
    top: 2em;

    :not(data-orbit-slide="headline-5") & {
      top: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS negation pseudo-class :not() for parent/ancestor elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084112/css-negation-pseudo-class-not-for-parent-ancestor-elements)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that it just doesn't work inside of the media quesries.