# CSS- how to select a selector which is not in specific controller?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following css:

```
.sign-up-cross.clone{
    top: 10px!important;
}
```

I have a modal with a "invite-contacts-modal" class which contain elements with "sign-up-cross clone" and I don't want that those element will have the css style above.

I try to use:

```
:not(.invite-contacts-modal) .sign-up-cross.clone{
    top: 10px!important;
}
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding IE8 is better to use this solution:

```
.sign-up-cross.clone {top: 10px;} /* declare 10px; */
.invite-contacts-modal .sign-up-cross.clone {top: 0;} /* set another value if the parent is .invite-contacts-modal */
```

Comment: @panther-I use Chrome.

Comment: @sarit rotshild: What you use isn't nearly as important as what your users may potentially use.

Comment: @BoltClock- it's not my point. I just want to know how can I select a selector which is not in a specific element

Comment: This solution applies to any browser - the IE8 issue isn't pertinent. There is simply no good solution other than an override. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084112/css-negation-pseudo-class-not-for-parent-ancestor-elements