# :not(X) not working

Tags: css, css-selectors

What is wrong with this? `.btn:not(.btn-float .btn) { ... }` I'd like to apply a css for all elements that have .btn class, except the ones within the div .btn-float

the result i'm getting, is that the class is not applied to any .btn element!

Thanks

Comment: are you writing just to write?? my issue is completely different as i'm not intending to use multiple :not() selectors!

Answer (score 2):

It should be :

```
div:not(.btn-float) .btn { ... }
```

This means select all `div`s that aren't `.btn-float`, then select the `.btn`s in them.

Comment: or `*:not(.btn-float) .btn { ... }` if we're not sure the parent element is a `div`

Comment: thanks Mr Geek for your reply. Actually what i want is to apply the css class for all `.btn` element except those within the `div.btn-float`

Comment: ah OK I see :) I'll try it right now and will let you know :)

Comment: @Websphere This does exactly what you're saying!

Comment: So if there's a div that's not .btn-float which either descends from or contains a div.btn-float, that gets matched despite the .btn-float, no?

Comment: @MrGeek, `*:not(.btn-float) .btn` doesn't work! it applies the css to also the `.btn` inside the `.btn-float` div :/

Comment: @Websphere: That's because https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084112/css-negation-pseudo-class-not-for-parent-ancestor-elements

Comment: @BoltClock, don't understand much your question, what I want to achieve, is simply apply a css class to all `.btn` elements, except those within a '.btn-float' div :)

Comment: @Websphere: Yes and the link is saying it's not possible with just one selector. You need to override.

Comment: OK, so that means i'll have to create 2 css classes? that's unfortunate :/

Comment: well, the easiest solution I found is to give a specific class name to the excluded buttons so i can simply use `.btn:not(.btn-excluded) { ... }`