# How do I remove all <br /> tags that aren't within <p> tags using regex?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm still getting used to using regex so I'm not entirely sure how to make this work.

I am not using `jQuery` and it is not the current `document`, rather I'm getting html from another source as a `string`. I don't care about the `<br />` tags that are outside of `<p>` tags, so I'd like to parse those out. I want to keep the ones that are within `<p>` tags to preserve their line breaks.

I need to change something like this:

```html
<body><br /><p>hello<br />there</p><br /></body>
```

To this:

```html
<body><p>hello<br />there</p></body>
```

What regex would I use to make this work?

Edit: More information, I'm trying to do this server side with Node.js. Because of that, I do not have access to `DOMParser`, I am, however, using [`html-dom-parser`](https://github.com/remarkablemark/html-dom-parser#readme). I'm parsing out these outer 
 tags before I pass it to that parser to reduce the resultant DOM tree object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DOMPArser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse the HTML content and then use [`:not()` pseudo-class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) to get all tags which are not `p` tag and then use [`>`(direct child selector)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) to get `br` tags which is the direct child of it(to avoid nested).

```js
let html = `<body><br />
  <p>hello<br />there </p><br /></body>`;


let parser = new DOMParser();
doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");


doc.querySelectorAll(':not(p) > br').forEach(ele => ele.remove())

console.log(doc.body.outerHTML)
```

Parsing HTML using RegExp is a bad idea:

[Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

---

For Node.js using [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) library, it may look alike,

```
let html = `<body><br />
  <p>hello<br />there</p><br /></body>`;

const dom = new JSDOM(html);


dom.window.document.querySelectorAll(':not(p) > br').forEach(ele => ele.remove())

console.log(dom.window.document.body.outerHTML)
```

**UPDATE :** If there is a chance for nested `br` tag within the p tag then check the ancestor element before removing.

For eg :

```js
let html = `<body><br />
  <p>hello<br />there<span><br/></span> </p><br /></body>`;


let parser = new DOMParser();
doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");


doc.querySelectorAll(':not(p) > br').forEach(ele => {
  // check for any p tag in parent level
  if (!ele.closest('p'))
    ele.remove()
})

console.log(doc.body.outerHTML)
```

Comment: Though OP says HTML source is string, this is definitely the way to go: let the browser parse the string and use CSS selectors to target the selection -- much easier.

Comment: That looks great! Unfortunately, I am doing this server side and I don't have access to `DOMParser`

Comment: Oh that looks much better than what I was using @PranavCBalan I'll try it!

Comment: `:not(p) > br` is dangerous: it can't handle `<p>text<span><br /><span>text</p>` for example. `:not(p) br` wouldn't help either

Comment: It does not have to be `span`. Could be any other tag (`em`, `strong`, `u`, `...`). It all depends on the source of the data. If it user generated data, then your code is to be considered broken

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55585573/476951) of [Pranav C Balan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3037257/pranav-c-balan):

The code `<...>.querySelectorAll(':not(p) > br').forEach(ele => ele.remove())`
is [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084112/css-negation-pseudo-class-not-for-parent-ancestor-elements), because it would remove all the `<br>` in `<p>`, when the former are themselves nested in non-`<p>` tags.

```js
let html = `<body><br>
  <p>hello <u>underline<br>underline</u><br>there </p><br></body>`;


let parser = new DOMParser();
doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");


doc.querySelectorAll(':not(p) > br').forEach(ele => ele.remove())

console.log(doc.body.outerHTML)

console.log(`This should've been:
<body>
  <p>hello <u>underline<br>underline</u><br>there </p></body>`)
```

To make it work, we need to get all the `<br>` elements and examine, if they are inside a `<p>` element, be it as a direct descendant or not. With jQuery you would use the `closest` method. We can use a VanillaJS method like this as described here: [PlainJS - Get closes element by selector](http://%20https://plainjs.com/javascript/traversing/get-closest-element-by-selector-39/)

```js
/** source: https://plainjs.com/javascript/traversing/get-closest-element-by-selector-39/ */
// matches polyfill
this.Element && function(ElementPrototype) {
    ElementPrototype.matches = ElementPrototype.matches ||
    ElementPrototype.matchesSelector ||
    ElementPrototype.webkitMatchesSelector ||
    ElementPrototype.msMatchesSelector ||
    function(selector) {
        var node = this, nodes = (node.parentNode || node.document).querySelectorAll(selector), i = -1;
        while (nodes[++i] && nodes[i] != node);
        return !!nodes[i];
    }
}(Element.prototype);

// closest polyfill
this.Element && function(ElementPrototype) {
    ElementPrototype.closest = ElementPrototype.closest ||
    function(selector) {
        var el = this;
        while (el.matches && !el.matches(selector)) el = el.parentNode;
        return el.matches ? el : null;
    }
}(Element.prototype);


let html = `<body><br>
  <p>hello <u>underline<br>underline</u><br>there </p><br></body>`;


let parser = new DOMParser();
doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");


doc.querySelectorAll(':not(p) > br').forEach(ele => {
    if (!ele.closest('p')) {
      ele.remove()
    }
  })

console.log(doc.body.outerHTML)
console.log(`That should be:
<body>
  <p>hello <u>underline<br>underline</u><br>there </p></body>`)
```

#### Addendum:

If you need to put spaces at the position where the removed `<br>` were, to prevent converting `a<br>b` to `ab` but rather `a b`, you can use this function inside the forEach

```
elm => {
    if (!elm.closest('p')) {
        elm.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(' '), elm);
        elm.remove();
    }
}
```