# querySelectorAll() match all h1's except from a div

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to match all `h1`'s on the document except from a `div` containing other `h1`'s, currently i can do `querySelectorAll('h1:not(.demo))` to get all `h1`'s with except `h1`'s with demo class.

But how can i do `querySelectorAll('h1:not(div#demo))` or similar thing?

Below is a sample html

```html
<body>
  <div><h1>First</h1> <h1>Second</h1></div>
  <div id="demo"><h1 class="demo">Third</h1></div>
  <div><h1>Fourth</h1></div>
<body>
```

Comment: please share your html?

Comment: try ```document.querySelectorAll('div:not(#demo) h1')```

Comment: I guess [slightly related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084112/css-negation-pseudo-class-not-for-parent-ancestor-elements) - interestingly, it's again about selecting all `h1` elements unless the parent is `div`.

Comment: @AsukaSong [doesn't work](https://jsbin.com/mezupileyu/edit?html,css,js,console,output) in either CSS nor `querySelectorAll` EDIT: ugh, sorry - OP changed the HTML, I was using the old one... [It does work](https://jsbin.com/pujibenoti/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Answer (score 1):

either this will work

```
 document.querySelectorAll('div:not(#demo) h1')
```

or this

```
document.querySelectorAll('h1:not(.demo)')
```

if you want to target all **h1** where don't have a class attribute you can do this way

```
document.querySelectorAll('h1:not([class])')
```

read more about  [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Answer (score 0):

You can first get all the divs *except* those you want to match, then run a query selector from those:

```js
const divsWhichArentDemo = document.querySelectorAll('div:not(#demo)');
const h1sWhichArentInDemoDivs = Array.prototype.slice.call(divsWhichArentDemo)
  .map(div => Array.prototype.slice.call(div.querySelectorAll('h1')))
  .flat();
  

console.dir(h1sWhichArentInDemoDivs);
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>First</h1>
  <h1>Second</h1>
</div>
<div id="demo">
  <h1 class="demo">Third</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Fourth</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can quite select the child headings from the divs with `>h1`

```js
let h1 = document.querySelectorAll('div:not(#demo)>h1');

console.log(h1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><h1>First</h1> <h1>Second</h1></div>
<div id="demo"><h1 class="demo">Third (demo)</h1></div>
<div><h1>Fourth</h1></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude `div` from collection by this way: `':not(div) > h1'`:

```js
var s = document.querySelectorAll(':not(div) > h1');
[...s].forEach((el) => el.innerHTML += ' changed');
```

```html
<div >
      <h1>h inside div 1</h1>
</div>
<h1>h outside div 1</h1>
<div id="d2">
      <h1>h inside div 2</h1>
</div>
<h1>h outside div 2</h1>
```

You may set a selector `':not(#demo) > h1'` then all `h1` will be treated except those ones inside `#demo`:

```js
var s = document.querySelectorAll(':not(#demo) > h1');
[...s].forEach((el) => el.innerHTML += ' changed');
```

```html
<div >
      <h1>h inside div 1</h1>
</div>
<h1>h outside div 1</h1>
<div id="demo">
      <h1>h inside div #demo</h1>
</div>
<h1>h outside div demo</h1>
```