# Target parent div, but not if it includes a nest class

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, document, dom-manipulation

I want to target a parent div using `document.querySelectorAll`.  But not if the div contains a nested div, with a particular class.

For example, in the example below, I want to grab the parent first and last `floatContainer` divs.  But not this second, because it contains `dropdown-container` class.

`document.querySelectorAll(".ej-form-field:not([dropdown-container])")` does not seem to be working.

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".ej-form-field:not([dropdown-container])"))
```

```html
<!-- GRAB THIS -->
<div id="floatContainer" class="ej-form-field">
  <label for="floatField">First name</label>
  <div class="input-container">
    <input id="floatField" class="ej-form-field-input-textbox" type="text">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- NOT THIS -->
<div id="floatContainer" class="ej-form-field">
  <label for="floatField">Last name</label>
  <div class="dropdown-container input-container">
    <input id="floatField" class="ej-form-field-input-textbox" type="text">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- GRAB THIS -->
<div id="floatContainer" class="ej-form-field">
  <label for="floatField">Telephone</label>
  <div class="input-container">
    <input id="floatField" class="ej-form-field-input-textbox" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS negation pseudo-class :not() for parent/ancestor elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084112/css-negation-pseudo-class-not-for-parent-ancestor-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code solve your problem.

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".ej-form-field>div:not(.dropdown-container)"))
```

Comment: This wouldn't grab the `.ej-form-field` itself but rather any div inside it which is a direct child but not a .dropdown-container.

Answer (score 1):

you must target a specific class not an attribute, ie:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".ej-form-field:not(.dropdown-container))
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found this option, which seemed to work as well:

`document.querySelectorAll("div.ej-form-field + :not(.dropdown-container)")`