# Select all elements and its nested childs using css :not()

Tags: css

```
<p>Reset works!</p>
<div class="no-reset">
  <p>dont reset!</p>
</div>


:not(".no-reset") p{
  margin: 0;
  color: red;

}
```

**I tried with**

I tried the above approach, not working for me.

I tried with this as well

```
*:not(".no-reset") p{
  margin: 0;
  color: red;

}
```

no luck !!

I just wanted to apply some styles under the "no-reset" child

here is link

https://jsfiddle.net/mrwL8ck9/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7084147/1427878

Comment: Can you explain what you actually mean here, with _"I just wanted to apply some styles under the "no-reset" child"_? If you want to format `p` elements that are descendants of `.no-reset`(?), then why is `:not()` in play? `.no-reset p` would be the matching selector for _that_.

Comment: I dont understand the reason why you want to make what a normal class does inversed. I mean you can add color: red to "no-reset" for example and color: black to "p" tag

Comment: it is just a use case. there too many things I have to play around this

Comment: @CBroe coz - I want to stylize all elements within DOM, however, those styles shouldn't be applied to the specific DIV and its child/descendants

Answer (score 2):

You could try with this selector :

```css
:not(.no-reset) > p
```

[`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) takes a list of selectors as argument, you don't have to add quotes `"`.

You should also use the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) `>` because the `p` element inside your `div.no-reset` is also a child of `body` that is matched by `:not(.no-reset)`.

```css
:not(.no-reset) > p {
  margin: 0;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Reset works!</p>
<div class="no-reset">
  <p>dont reset!</p>
</div>
```

You could also use [revert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert). Note that this keyword is not supported on IE.

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  color: red;
}

.no-reset p {
  margin: revert;
  color: revert;
}
```

```html
<p>Reset works!</p>
<div class="no-reset">
  <p>dont reset!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: P is not a direct child, hierarchy can be anything

Comment: @Chandrakant I added another possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try and put it like this:

```
:not(.no-reset) p {
  margin: 0;
  color: red;
}
```

The pseudo-selector `:not` doesn't need double quotes for selecting an element.
I hope that my info on the matter can help you. Cheers

Comment: still it is not working  work as expected